# Denormalization of numpy matrix is not correct

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, neural-networks, python

I have a $4D$-array of shape $(1948, 60, 2, 3)$ which I normalized to a range of $[0,1]$

a sample of how it looks is below:

```
original_mat = array([[[  3.93048840e-05,   7.70215296e-04,  
1.13865805e-03], [ 1.11679799e-04,  -7.04810066e-04,   1.83552688e-04]])
```

After normalization `(x - x_min)/ (x_max - x_min)`

```
predicted =   array([[ 0.19302673, -0.03372632, -0.23808828],
         [ 0.30002626, -0.71888705,  0.71468331]])
```

I fed this input to a neural network to predict a similar output, after convergence my resultant matrix looked the same and to de-normalize it, I did,

```
denormed_matrix = predicted*(xmax - xmin) + xmin
`denormed_matrix` = [[-0.62747524, -0.72737077,  0.70058271],
         [-0.39488326, -0.18533665, -1.48910199]],
```

I expected it to have same order of magnitude values `( e-03 to e-05)`, but the matrix didn't scale down in magnitude, it had similar values like the normalized one.

1. Am I missing any point here?
2. Are my calculation correct?

**EDIT**

**CODE for Normalization**

```
### Get min, max value aming all elements for each column
    

x = np.asarray(poseList)
    x_min = np.min(x, axis=tuple(range(x.ndim-1)), keepdims=1)
    x_max = np.max(x, axis=tuple(range(x.ndim-1)), keepdims=1)
    #
    ### Normalize with those min, max values leveraging broadcasting
    normalized = (x - x_min)/ (x_max - x_min)
    normalized = 2.0*normalized - 1.0    # noralizing in the range [-1,1]
    #
    print "final_save"
    
    In [75]: norm.shape
    Out[75]: (309, 60, 2, 3)
    
    In [16]: x_max
    Out[16]: array([[[[ 0.10778677,  0.16254221,  0.1198302 ]]]])
    
    In [17]: x_min
    Out[17]: array([[[[-0.56810854, -0.21604319, -0.37091526]]]])
```

**Code for Denormalization**
Following this formula $$X=\frac{(X_{max}-X_{min})(X'-a)}{b-a}+X_{min}$$

```
normalized = np.load('/home/normalized.npy')
normalized = normalized+ 1  #[a,b] = [-1,1]
diff = x_max - x_min
numerator = diff * normalized
denormalized = (numerator/2.0 ) + x_min
```

Comment: Are the values of `xmax` and `xmin` the same in the two uses?

Comment: Yes. I have saved the values.
Is the problem the way I am doing the calculation, like, should I be inverting the denormalized matrix?

Comment: Just to clarify, does the resultant matrix look like the normalized input?  Also, is a parenthesis missing from your normalization expression?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yeah! Thanks..I have edited the formula. Yes, my denormed output looks like predicted output. I have included a sample of how it looks above.

Comment: But your predicted matrix is not in the range $[0,1]$ as you say.  If you wanted that range, you'd do `(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin)`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, Sure, but my understanding is, the `original_mat` normalized(let's call it as normalized_mat). `normalized_mat` is in the range [0,1]. Now, I feed the `normalized_mat` to a function(neural network) that outputs `predicted` of same dimensions. Now, I should be denormalizing the `predicted` right?
Also, I edited the normalization formula again..sorry about that!

Comment: `predicted` above contains negative numbers...

Comment: @FabioSomenzi That is because, I tried normalizing it to [-1,1] as well. I convert them back to [0,1] for some analysis purposes from [-1,1]. It's more of a typo that I missed including this range. I do, `2*(x - x_min)/ (x_max - x_min) - 1` to get [-1,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The denormalization formula is wrong.

Normalization:

$X' = a + \frac{\left(X-X_{\min}\right)\left(b-a\right)}{X_{\max} - X_{\min}}$

Denormalization (inverse formula):

$X =  \frac{(X_{\max}-X_{\min})(X'-a)}{b-a} + X_{\min}$

---

Example with original_mat(0,0):

$X' = 2\frac{(3.93048840 + 7.04810066)}{(7.70215296 + 7.04810066)}-1$

$X' = 2\frac{10.97858906}{14.75025362}-1$

$X' = 0.48859665$

denormalization:

$X =  \frac{14.75025362(0.48859665+1)}{2} - 7.04810066$

$X =  \frac{21.95717813}{2} - 7.04810066$

$X =3.93048840$

I hope I have been of help,
best regards,

Marco.

Comment: Solid answer. About as good an answer as one could hope for concerning programming issues on a mathematics site!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for correcting me..I am still; not getting the right answer, I normalize and renormalize, but it doesn't work. I have updated the code in the question details above.

Comment: sorry, maybe I did not understand the problem. I'm not very good at python, could you just show the input matrix, the minimum, the maximum, and the output obtained? rather, why do you have more than a maximum and a minimum?

Comment: @MarcoD.G. Hey, the issue ios resolved, it was a python code error. Thanks for your effort